# Python3 make file into dictionary ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

My problem is how to convert text files into dictionaries
This is my code. And i got error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

[And this is the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM2yP.jpg)

```
filename = ("/users/Reza/Downloads/anyar.txt")

commands = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
for line in fh:
    command, description = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
    commands[command] = description.strip()

print(commands)
```

pardon my english.Thanks

[The dictonary output of the coding must like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1TWF.jpg)

Comment: At least one line in the file does not contain a space (possibly the last line is empty). Then `command, description = ...` will cause that error.

Comment: Your first data line doesn't have space as pointed out by @DeepSpace, hence the error.

Comment: Ok i figured it, this is the content of the file
**Barang masuk adalah
1.Detergent /id:B001 /Jumlah:500
2.Sabun Mandi /id:B002 /jumlah:300
3.Pasta gigi /id:B003 /Jumlah:400**

my question is can make that file into dictionary like this : 
{'id' ='B001,B002,B003', 'nama'='Detergent,Sabun mandi,Pasta gigi, 'Jumlah'='500,300,400'}

Comment: Edit the question to correct problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting error because there were no space in first data line and data should be split by / not space. to get the expected output you can use below sample code.

```
import re
filename = ("input_file.txt")
has_header = True
count = 1
commands = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if has_header == True and count == 1:
            count+=1
            continue
        nama, id, Jumlah = line.strip().split('/')
        commands['nama'] = commands.get('nama','') + nama.split('.')[1] + ','
        commands['id'] = commands.get('id','') + id.split(':')[1] + ','
        commands['Jumlah'] = commands.get('Jumlah','') + Jumlah.split(':')[1] + ','

print(commands)
```

Sample output:

```
{'nama': 'Detergent ,Sabun Mandi ,Pasta gigi ,', 'id': 'B001 ,B002 ,B003 ,', 'Jumlah': '500,300,400,'}
```

Comment: ty for the response 
i will try it